# Displaying umlauts from coded string in TextMeshPro in Unity

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, text

I'm trying to display some text in Unity in various TextMeshPro text-fields.

The text is taken from a CSV-file and saved in a string variable.

Assigning this string variable to the text-component it also works fine, 
but all umlauts (ä,ö,ü) are shown as squares (I assume the sign for not found characters). 

Also the Line-break \n command won't work. (Found a workaround with < br>).

Typing these characters and commands though directly in the text-field from the inspector work fine.

Currently the Font I'm using is LiberationSans SDF.

Using a different Font might not work, because the Font already contains these characters, but just won't recognize them.
Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Thanks allot

Comment: Try using a fallback font. Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1Cj16TB1l0).

Comment: Umlaute should work in the default font (I just tried), but maybe there's an encoding issue in regards to the incoming data. What happens if you select the LiberationSans.ttf font asset and in the details pane, choose e.g. Character: Unicode (and later, others), hit Apply, and try again?

Comment: Thanks allot for the help.
I tried both and after further searching I found out, that my CSV-file is not encoded in UTF 8.
Changing the encoding solved it. Now I only need to figure out how to change the macro in excel to export it in UTF 8 (it's bugging a bit). :S

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research it turned out that the CSV-file was encoded in `ANSI`.

To Display umlauts the CSV-file needs to be in the format of `UTF 8`.